# I get the error 'Error: Request failed with status code 408' when attempting to make stripe payment in production

Tags: firebase, react-native, axios, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to make stripe payments in my react native app using the stripe.charges.create function and library axios. This currently works fine in test mode, so using the secret and publishable test keys. However, when amending the keys to live as well as changing the source I get the following error: [Error: Request failed with status code 408] .
Looking at the stripe docs https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors it appears that this may be due to a missing parameter, ...'Codes in the 4xx range indicate an error that failed given the information provided (e.g., a required parameter was omitted, a charge failed, etc.).'
Could I be missing the customer id in my stripe.charges.create function shown below? The stripe docs mentions that for card sources the customer id is required, https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create . If this is required where do I add this in my code in order to make live payments? API Keys obtained from stripe dashboard.

**Testing**
`index.js` file

```
const stripe = require("stripe")("**SK_TEST**");

exports.payWithStripe = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  stripe.charges
    .create({
      amount: request.body.amount,
      currency: request.body.currency,
      source: "tok_mastercard",
    })
    .then((charge) => {
      response.send(charge);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

**Production**
`index.js` file

```
const stripe = require("stripe")("SK_LIVE");

exports.payWithStripe = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  stripe.charges
    .create({
      amount: request.body.amount,
      currency: request.body.currency,
      source: "request.body.token",
    })
    .then((charge) => {
      response.send(charge);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

**`CardScreen.js` file**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import stripe from "tipsi-stripe";
import Button from "./components/Button";
import { demoCardFormParameters } from "./demodata/demodata";
import axios from "axios";

stripe.setOptions({ publishableKey: "PK_LIVE" });

export default class CardScreen extends PureComponent {
  static title = "Card Form";

  state = {
    loading: false,
    paymentMethod: null,
  };

  handleCardPayPress = async () => {
    try {
      this.setState({ loading: true, paymentMethod: null });

      const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentRequestWithCardForm({
        smsAutofillDisabled: true,
      });

      this.setState({ loading: false, paymentMethod });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
  };

  makePayment = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://us-central1-appname-90059.cloudfunctions.net/payWithStripe",
      data: {
        amount: 50,
        currency: "gbp",
        token: this.state.paymentMethod,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, paymentMethod } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Card Form Example</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instruction}>
          Click button to show Card Form dialog.
        </Text>
        <Button
          text="Enter your card and pay"
          loading={loading}
          onPress={this.handleCardPayPress}
        />
        <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
          {paymentMethod && (
            <>
              <Text style={styles.instruction}>
                Payment Method: {JSON.stringify(paymentMethod.id)}
              </Text>

              <Button
                text="Make Payment"
                loading={loading}
                onPress={this.makePayment}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I removed the the quote tags from the source, so source: request.body.token but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you log the error and share the complete screenshot ?

Comment: [Thu Apr 22 2021 21:32:14.370]  LOG      [Error: Request failed with status code 408] - This is the error when using the live keys.

Comment: [Thu Apr 22 2021 21:51:30.788]  LOG      {"config": {"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter], "data": "{\"amount\":50,\"currency\":\"gbp\",\"token\":{\"card\":{\"funding\":\"credit\",\"expYear\":2026,\"expMonth\":11,\"last4\":\"4242\",\"country\":\"US\",\"brand\":\"visa\"},\"id\":\"pm_1Ij9UKFsVwVqkkE8gj0u03bj\",\"billingDetails\":{\"address\":{\"state\":null,\"line2\":null,\"line ...    The logs for using test keys. This works fine

Comment: I'm not sure the charges API work at all currently, because at least the EU has forced SCA on payments, so Stripe migrated to using payment intents API. Read more here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents

Comment: ok thanks. And how do I use this stripe.paymentIntents.create method? Do I just remove the source field and add the field payment_method_types as in the docs to make a real payment?