# Stripe error the customer has not entered their payment method in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have integrated **flutter_stripe 2.0.1** plugins in my flutter application using Firebase CLI. getting a successful response of paymentIntent from firebase provided URL. But in the Stripe dashboard payment status is **Incomplete**.

Below is my node.js code
**index.js file**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey);

exports.stripePayment = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {  
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 1,
        currency: 'usd'
    },
        function(err, paymentIntent) {
            if(err != null){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.json({
                    paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
                })
            }
        }
    )

});
```

Below is my flutter code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Stripe.publishableKey = stripePublishableKey;
  Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'merchant.flutter.stripe.test'; //any string works
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: DashboradPage(),
      );
  }
}

class DashboradPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboradPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboradPageState createState() => _DashboradPageState();
}

class _DashboradPageState extends State<DashboradPage> {
  Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntentData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Stripe Examples'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            makePayment();
          },
          child: Text('Pay Amount'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> makePayment() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://us-central1-stripeflutterdemo.cloudfunctions.net/stripePayment');

    final header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url, headers: header);
      paymentIntentData = json.decode(response.body);
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
            paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData?['paymentIntent'] ?? '',
          applePay: true,
          googlePay: true,
          style: ThemeMode.light,
          merchantCountryCode: 'US',
          merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter Stripe Store Demo',
        ));
        setState(() {});
       displayPaymentSheet();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      displaySnackbar(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
      // await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(
      //   parameters: PresentPaymentSheetParameters(
      //     clientSecret: paymentIntentData?['paymentIntent'] ?? '',
      //     confirmPayment: true,
      //   ),
      // );

      setState(() {
        paymentIntentData = null;
      });
      displaySnackbar('Payment succesfully completed');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      displaySnackbar(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void displaySnackbar(String msg) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(msg),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the postman response of URL mentioned in makePayment()

[image]

I have used payment sheet, when I clicked on the Pay button it is redirecting to webview (Authentication completed) but in the Stripe dashboard payment status is **Incomplete**.

Stripe Dashboard Payment Event data
**PaymentIntent status:requires_payment_method,
PaymentIntent status:requires_action**

```
From Stripe
payment_intent.payment_failed
View event detail
Event data
{
  "id": "pi_3JpZh7SIKwX0CSUQ0sUoM9wK",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "last_payment_error": {
    "message": "As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports",
    "param": "description",
    "payment_method": {
      "id": "pm_1JpZijSIKwX0CSUQ7u91wths",
      "object": "payment_method",
      "billing_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": "US",
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": "45612",
          "state": null
        },
        "email": null,
        "name": null,
        "phone": null
      },
      "card": {
        "brand": "visa",
        "checks": {
          "address_line1_check": null,
          "address_postal_code_check": "unchecked",
          "cvc_check": "unchecked"
        },
        "country": "US",
        "exp_month": 4,
        "exp_year": 2044,
        "fingerprint": "EK9VAoccqqCLBqQk",
        "funding": "credit",
        "generated_from": null,
        "last4": "4242",
        "networks": {
          "available": [
            "visa"
          ],
          "preferred": null
        },
        "three_d_secure_usage": {
          "supported": true
        },
        "wallet": null
      },
      "created": 1635431806,
      "customer": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "type": "card"
    },
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "next_action": null,
  "status": "requires_payment_method",
  "amount": 1,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_received": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "charges": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_3JpZh7SIKwX0CSUQ0sUoM9wK"
  },
  "client_secret": "pi_3JpZh7SIKwX0CSUQ0sUoM9wK_secret_oVhK5CmrcHjImvFMyoo51GCXy",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1635431705,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "description": null,
  "invoice": null,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": null,
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": "off_session",
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

Below is the iPhone screenshot

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was using flutter_stripe package and had exactly the same problem. Got success in the app logs but in Stripe logs, the payment was incomplete because not payment method added. Been looking for a while about this issue, I fixed it by adding the `Stripe.instance.confirmPaymentSheetPayment();` after `await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet()` like this:

```
 await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((e) {
      Stripe.instance.confirmPaymentSheetPayment();
    });
```

I find their documentation very confusing, especially with the Stripe server side.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Very helpful, I had wasted about three hours on this :( thank mate

Answer (score 1):

In your currency code make sure that is same as in your Stripe account. I solve this problem by doing this

i.e

```
paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent('10', 'INR');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents), the `required_payment_method` message as a `status` means you have not attached a payment method to your payment intent:

> When the PaymentIntent is created, it has a status of requires_payment_method until a payment method is attached.

There is an official [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments) explaining how to integrate Stripe payments with your Firebase backend. It provides all the required code and steps to properly set up payments with Stripe. In the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/stripe/functions/index.js#L97) inside the `index.js` file, they include additional objects when creating the payment intent with `stripe.paymentIntents.create()`

```
const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
    {
      amount,
      currency,
      customer,
      Payment_method, //payment method when creating the payment intent
      off_session: false,
      confirm: true,
      confirmation_method: 'manual',
    },
    { idempotencyKey }
  );
```

Since your sample is missing the payment method, it could explain the error you are receiving, as the `PaymentIntent` is being created without a payment method. I recommend following the guide to cover all the required steps to avoid further errors that might be present. You can also see the full sample code, which is documented and can be customized for your use case and the `flutter_stripe` library.

Comment: thankyou for the detailed answer. but if I do any changes in the index.js file, it throws an error of 408. can you tell me the changes in my code above, although it is a demo application which we will be integrating into our project.

Comment: A [408 error](https://httpstatuses.com/408) means the request is missing required parameters. There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67225802/) in which required parameters show this error in a Flutter app which uses Stripe payments. You can review the `flutter_stripe` [documentation](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example) as there is an example app which can help you formulate the correct requests.